# Programmatically select DrawingObject in HWindowControlWPF

Tags: c#, wpf, halcon

I'd like to select a created DrawingObject to highlight it and show the handles without the user needing to click it. I am using Halcon 13 and tried using `SendMouseDoubleClickEvent()` [(Docu)](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/send_mouse_double_click_event.html) but this only seems to be available for the new Halcon Smart Window, which is currently not an option for me as it interacts differently with the Halcon-Procedures. I also tried to use `SelectObj()` [(Docu)](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/select_obj.html) but this seems to do something entirely different.

I have:

- a reference to the HWindowControlWPF
- the ID of the HWindowControlWPF
- the ID of the DrawingObject

Any help or hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a proper solution to this problem but I found a hack that achieves the same result:

First, detach all drawing objects apart from the one you want to show as selected via `DetachDrawingObjectFromWindow`. Then, reattach them via `AtachDrawingObjectFromWindow`.

This works because the Halcon Window automatically selects the last attached drawing object.